# fxml giving url is not registered resource error in intellij

Tags: javafx, fxml

Hi I'm new to javafx fxml, but the following line is giving me an error stating url is not registered.

`<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">`
That is directly from the oracle tutorial.

Comment: Can you add details about your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that IntelliJ is looking for an XSD file at that URL, but it isn't finding one. Open Preferences and go to Languages and Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs. Under "Ignored Schemas and DTDs", add "http://javafx.com/fxml".